# Multiple Model data to display in single template

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

i am using django detail view to display single company detail. But now i want to display on the same template list of users who are employee of that company. But i am using User Auth table. How can i display multiple view like detail view for company and list view for users of that company.

```
class CompanyDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = Company
    template_name = 'company/company-detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'companies'

class UserListView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'users/users.html'
    context_object_name = 'users'
```

User should be displayed only of that company

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User and UserProfile Data

```
class CompanyUserDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'company/company-detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        id_ = self.kwargs.get("pk")
        # print('printinh,,: ',id_)        
        context = super(CompanyUserDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['companydetail'] = Company.objects.get(pk=1)

        context['userlist'] = User.objects.filter(userprofile__user_company_id=id_)
        return context
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that you are using User Auth Table, I am assuming you are using default Django User Model. If you are using a model which connected to User with OneToOne relation to store additional data, then you must be storing company information there. Like:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User)
   company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
```

If you do so, then you don't need to do any changes in the view to fetch user data. You can fetch data [using related objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/relations/). Like this in Template of `CompanyDetailView`:

```
{% for profile in object.profile_set.all %}
   {{ profile.user }}
{% endfor %}
```